# iOS 8.4.1 jailbreak and if not what is the reason

Tags: jailbreak, ios

So I wanted to jailbreak my iPhone 4s but I read that this new iOS kills the some softwares that used to jailbreak prep versions and also I found a semi jailbreak which isn't fully functional and requires a donation.

Are there jailbreaks available for iOS 8.4.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. People have jailbroken 8.4.1; but will wait until iOS 9 is released to release the hack. (They don't want apple to fix it for iOS 9, then have to find another hack)